# What's the best way to register a new user on Python-Social-Auth without a social backend?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I know that can sound a little confuse, but some sites allows mutiple ways to sign up, like using a social network (FB or TW, of course I'm using python-social-auth for this porpouse) or use a form to create a new user...

are there a way to register new user into my site using a custom registration form (i.e. using a common set of fields like, email, password, first name, etc) and keep it integrated with python-social-auth?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you think they won't be integrated? python-social-auth will check if certain social account exists in the database and login the related user for it, it doesn't add a user model or anything, it uses your user model.

Comment: So the correct way to sign up a new user is "creating" a new one on my custom user model ?

Comment: The user can signup with the usual email/username mechanism that you implement (or the app you use implements), then the user can associate a social account (like in a user dashboard in your site where the user has the option to do it). Later the user can login with usual username/email or the social account.

Comment: Also remember to have `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` in the list of `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` besides the social ones you want to use - http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html#authentication-backends

Answer (score 0):

You can register new user at any time with this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user(username='new_user',
                                email='test@dot.com',
                                password='test')
```

And then add his social account.